# How to remove or hide port no from url?

Tags: asp.net-core, url, port, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have created a web application using **blazor** asp net core and publish as a folder profile, it is working fine on https://192.168.0.3:5001 but i want to remove/hide the port no from url. i am not using IIS express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio you can go to the menu option "Project => YourApp's Properties" and you'll find the url addresses of your app in the "Debug" tab.

Try tweaking them, but you'll have to be sure to adjust the NAT inside your intranet for it to work as you want. If you pretend to run the app just on a single PC I'm not sure you can get rid of the port number at all...